# SQL server get Date out of DateTime in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a datetime format to a date format.
I can only find examples where they use the `getDate()` Method.

Well I would like to convert a existing value from the table.

I tried:

```
CAST(ActiveTo AS date)
```

That didn't work... I get an empty result

Comment: Show us your query and a sample record.

Comment: what doesnt work.could you post more info

Comment: Then the value of `ActiveTo` is either null or its not a datetime data type or you are not telling us something.

Comment: You can refer more at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asphttp://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: **That didn't work** is not the way to describe a failure. Note that the `Date` datatype was introduced in 2008 version, meaning that if you are working with an older version you should get an error. Also note, that if your sql client is a .net program, there is no `Date` datatype in `.Net`, so you will get an instance of `DateTime` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for GETDATE():

```
CONVERT (Date, GETDATE())
```

And this for your existing column:

```
CONVERT (Date, ActiveTo)
```

For more, take a look in this documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188383.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CONVERT (ActiveTo, GETDATE()) 'Date Part Only'
```

Comment: This will not work.   Check the usage of the CONVERT function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
CONVERT(DATE,ActiveTo)
```

If ActiveTo is DateTime Column

Answer (score 0):

Use CONVERT with proper format,

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

Few samples,

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), ActiveTo)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ActiveTo, 10)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ActiveTo, 110)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ActiveTo, 6)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ActiveTo, 106)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), ActiveTo, 113)
```

and their respective outputs,

```
Nov 04 2014 11:45 PM
11-04-14
11-04-2014
04 Nov 14
04 Nov 2014
04 Nov 2014 11:45:34:243
```